# WriteBInaryFile from JS same way as C#

Tags: javascript, node.js

I having trouble writing array from JS, Specially with decimal values which are greater then 100.
If i use  c# `File.WriteAllBytes` method i get different output then when I use nodejs `appendFile`
I am using `appendFile` and not `writeFile` because its within a loop.
I`ve taken hardcoded array for testing and this is what i got:

**C#:**

```
byte[] arr2 = new byte[] {78, 51, 49, 48, 48, 48, 85, 49, 164, 0, 67, 54, 52, 49, 53, 57, 52, 57, 52,
                             66, 52, 50, 49, 48, 69, 57, 70, 69, 55, 70, 50, 52, 70, 48, 69, 52, 70, 70,
                             50, 67, 67, 55, 50, 67, 69, 54, 53, 56, 66, 67, 53, 66};

File.WriteAllBytes("test", arr2);
```

**JS:**

```
const fsp = require("fs").promises;
...
...

const writeDataToFileFile = async (data: Buffer) => {
  const appTempPath = app.getPath("temp");
  const pathToWrite = path.join(appTempPath, "test.bin");
  await fsp.appendFile(pathToWrite, `${data}`);
};

const arr = [
    78, 51, 49, 48, 48, 48, 85, 49, 164, 0, 67, 54, 52, 49, 53, 57, 52, 57, 52,
    66, 52, 50, 49, 48, 69, 57, 70, 69, 55, 70, 50, 52, 70, 48, 69, 52, 70, 70,
    50, 67, 67, 55, 50, 67, 69, 54, 53, 56, 66, 67, 53, 66,
  ];
  logger.info(arr);
  const bufferFromArr = Buffer.from(arr);
  logger.info(bufferFromArr);
  await writeDataToFileFile(bufferFromArr);
```

M problem with JS is the `�` which represents the value 164, when logging the buffer.

this is the buffer: `N31000U1� C64159494B4210E9FE7F24F0E4FF2CC72CE658BC5B`

c# file output: N31000U1₪.C64

JS file output: N31000U1ן¿½.C64

**EDIT:**
I figured out the c# converts the 164 into hex and then writes it, The question is how to achive this in JS

Comment: You can write the buffer directly, not via a template literal.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489360/how-to-write-binary-not-utf-8-to-file)

Comment: Your`e right. Its also solved me the issue.